# How to find the maximal paths of an acyclic directed graph?

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks

Given an acyclic directed graph, say with

```
edges = {{1, 12}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {4, 5}, {7, 5}, {8, 10}, {9, 10}, {10, 11}};
```

the maximal paths (if that is the right term) can be found as

```
With[{pathfinder = FindShortestPath[DirectedEdge @@@ edges],
       subgraphs = ConnectedComponents[UndirectedEdge @@@ edges],
          begins = Complement[edges[[All, 1]], edges[[All, 2]]],
            ends = Complement[edges[[All, 2]], edges[[All, 1]]]},

  pathfinder @@@ Join @@ (Tuples[{begins ⋂ #, ends ⋂ #}] & /@ subgraphs)]
```

`Out[]= {{2, 3, 1, 12}, {4, 5}, {7, 5}, {8, 10, 11}, {9, 10, 11}}`

How to do this with graph functions so as to reduce the complexity?

Comment: Can you explain the problem in plain English, in addition to your code?

Comment: You can find the source and sink vertices using `Pick[VertexList[g], VertexOutDegree[g], 0]` and `Pick[VertexList[g], VertexInDegree[g], 0]` if `g` is a directed graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ClearAll[sstsp, shortestSourceToSinkPaths, highlightPaths]
sstsp = shortestSourceToSinkPaths = Module[{g = #, 
   sources = GraphComputation`SourceVertexList @ #, 
   sinks = GraphComputation`SinkVertexList @ #}, 
 Join @@ (Module[{v = #, vsinks = Intersection[sinks, VertexOutComponent[g, #]]}, 
   Join @@ (MinimalBy[Length][FindPath[g, v, #, Infinity, All] ]& /@ sinks)]&/@sources)]&;

highlightPaths = Module[{g = #}, 
   HighlightGraph[g, Style[Subgraph[g, #], Thick] & /@ sstsp[g],
    PlotLabel -> Style[sstsp[g], Black, 12, "Panel", Background -> None]]]&;
```

**Examples:**

```
edges = {{1, 12}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {4, 5}, {7, 5}, {8, 10}, {9, 10}, {10, 11}};
g = Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ edges, VertexShapeFunction->"Name"];

highlightPaths @ g
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[123]
g2 =  RandomGraph[PriceGraphDistribution[10, 3, 2], 
  DirectedEdges -> True, VertexShapeFunction-> "Name", ImageSize->600];

highlightPaths @ g2
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming by "maximal" path you mean the maximum-length *shortest* path between two vertexes.  (If not, you can always make a longer path by wandering around the graph... unhelpful.)

```
g = Graph[edges];
First@GroupBy[
  Flatten[
    Table[{i, j, Length@FindShortestPath[g, i, j]}, 
      {i, Length[edges]}, {j, i - 1}], 1], #[[3]] &]
```

(* {{2,1,3}, {7, 4, 3}} *)

which means that the longest path is of length 3 and is between vertexes 2 an 1 and between vertexes 7 and 4.

This function is extremely fast, finding the longest paths in `g =  RandomGraph[{20000, 40000}];` in $0.014693$ seconds.

Try:

```
g = RandomGraph[{20000, 40000}];
Timing[First@
  GroupBy[Flatten[
    Table[{i, j, Length@FindShortestPath[g, i, j]}, 
      {i, Length[edges]}, {j, i - 1}], 1], #[[3]] &]]
```